# How do I push letters to into a string?

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop, char

I want to take the var ascii and put it into a string. The code only returns each char within the loop.

```
    function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!
        var newStr = str;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
            var letter = str.charAt(i);
            var code = letter.charCodeAt();

            if (code > 77){
                ascii = code - 13;
            }
            else if (code === 32 ){
                ascii = code;
            }
            else{
                var ascii = code + 13;
            }
        }
    }

    rot13("SERR PBQR PNZC"); //returns FREE CODE CAMP
```

Comment: Now spend 10 seconds and imagine you're somebody that sees that code for the first time. Do you seriously think your "question" is answerable?

Comment: you already have it `//sipher += String.fromCharCode(ascii);`. For everyone else - it's a ROT13 homework https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13

Comment: Need more description of the problem and pin point where in the code is the issue

Answer (score 0):

To answer you, you already have written the code, but just used messed up a bit here and there -

```
   function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!
        console.log (str);
        var newStr = str;
        var ascii = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < newStr.length; i++){
            var letter = newStr.charAt(i);
            //console.log (letter);
            var code = letter.charCodeAt();
            //console.log (code);


            if (code > 77){
                ascii = code - 13;
                //console.log (ascii);
            }
            else if (code === 32 ){
                ascii = code;
                //console.log (ascii);
            }
            else{
                ascii = code + 13;
                //console.log (ascii);
            }
            var sipher = "";
            sipher = String.fromCharCode(ascii);
            newStr += sipher;

        }
        console.log (sipher);

            return newStr;
    }
```